# mmenu keep parent menu a link

Tags: javascript, mmenu

I am using js mmenu on the shopify site. I run into issue which I cant figure out.

When there is a dropdown menu, parent link becomes not clickable and has #mm-0 at the end of it. I need to keep it as is and link to its own page. 
You can see code below.  Right now Links "Products" and "About" go to https://www.irestorelaser.com/products/irestore-laser-hair-growth-system#mm-0 . Any help would be great!

```
<div id="nav" >
      <ul>
      <li ><a href="/pages/how-irestore-works">How it works</a></li>
          <li class="Selected"><a href="/products/irestore-laser-hair-growth-system">Products</a>
    <ul>
           <li class="Selected"><a href="/products/irestore-laser-hair-growth-system">Laser Helmet</a></li>

              <li ><a href="/collections/all">All Products</a></li>

              </ul>
            </li>
          <li ><a href="/pages/about-us">About</a>
              <ul>
                <li ><a href="/pages/warranty">Warranty</a></li>


              </ul>
            </li>



      </ul>
    </div>
```